# react-slick stop autoplay when window is resized / (maybe only on touch device)

Tags: reactjs, carousel, slick.js, react-slick

#### env

```
"react-slick": "^0.14.7"
"slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
```

#### replication

[rails repo] that can replicate this issue (https://github.com/github0013/on_window_resize)

```bsh
git clone ..
cd ...
rails s 
open http://localhost:3000
```

#### issue

this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20bumb4g/2557/) template has the same problem.
Try resizing the window.  The image scrolling should stop.

related to https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/543

I am currently avoiding this issue by using `slickNext()` with debounce.
https://github.com/github0013/on_window_resize/blob/master/app/javascript/packs/with_debounce.jsx#L24

If I don't use `slickNext()`, https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/543 this solution didn't do the trick.

#### is this my issue or ...?

[demo](http://neostack.com/opensource/react-slick)
doesn't have this issue for some reasons.   Has anybody came across the same issue?

Comment: Same problem, no solution yet.